# How does this MIN macro work?

Tags: c, macros

Pardon me if this is a dumb question. I can't seem to figure out how the following MIN macro works:

```cpp
#define MIN(x, y)  (y) ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))
```

Comment: `<` is less than, `-` is minus, or am I missing something?

Comment: Show us what you do, describe what are you trying to do, and what is not working for you.

Comment: They do the same thing in a macro that they do outside a macro. Your question is unanswerable unless you show us the macro definition.

Answer (score 3):

A macro is a pre-processor directive, meaning that wherever it's used, it will be replaced by the relevant piece of code.

If you edit in your `MIN` macro, me or someone else here should be able to help explain it.

Example:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

#define PLUS +

int main() {
    printf("%d", (1 PLUS 3));
}
```

This should merely output `4`.

### EDIT

Let's break down your macro..

We have,

```
(y) ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))
```

- Let's take the last part, `(x < y)`. This is `1` if `x` is smaller than `y` and `1` else. Therefore, `-(x < y)` would be the `0xffffffff` if `x` is smaller and `0` else.
- So now, `((x ^ y) & -(x < y))` becomes `((x ^ y) & 0xffffffff)`, i.e., `(x ^ y)`, if x is smaller than y, and `((x ^ y) & 0)`, i.e., `0` else.
- Therefore, the entire macro becomes `(y) ^ (x ^ y)`, i.e., `x`, if x is smaller and `(y) ^ 0`, i.e., `y` else. This is indeed the `MIN` functionality required.

Comment: Thank you. I edited in the MIN macro.

Comment: @Tim: Answer updated. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

If x is less than y, then:

- `(x < y)` is 1.
- `-(x < y)` is -1.
- `((x ^ y) & -(x < y))` is `((x ^ y) & -1)`, which is `(x ^ y)`, because `(anything & -1) == anything`, because -1 is all '1' bits.
- `y ^ (x ^ y)` is `x`, because XOR is commutative, and the y's cancel out.

If y is less than or equal to x, then:

- `(x < y)` is 0.
- `-(x < y)` is 0.
- `((x ^ y) & -(x < y))` is `((x ^ y) & 0)`, which is `0`, because `(anything & 0) == 0`, because 0 is all '0' bits.
- `y ^ 0` is `y`.

The macro currently has a serious bug, though: it needs parenthesis around the outer expression or it will run into muddles with operator precedence when used in other expressions. For example, `MIN(2, 3) * 4` currently expands to `(3) ^ ((2 ^ 3) & -(2 < 3)) * 4`, which evaluates to 7, instead of the correct 8, because the multiplication is done before the final XOR. It would also be a good idea to put parentheses around each argument substitution for the same reason:

```
#define MIN(x, y) ((y) ^ (((x) ^ (y)) & -((x) < (y))))
```

The macro still only works if the platform uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integers, and it may not be any faster than the obvious definition of MIN which is:

```
#define MIN(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if `x < y`, the result of `-(x < y)` will be only 0's. So  it'll be equivalent to:

```
y ^ 0
```

Which is `y`.

- `<` has no special meaning, it means *smaller than*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the explanations posted by others in the comments, you should also be aware of side-effects in macros when an argument is evaluated more than once when the macro is expanded.

In the case of the usual C-style definition of `MIN(x,y)` (e.g. as pointed out by @Boann) note that `x, y` are both expanded **twice**.  Your original definition expands `x` twice and `y` three times.  Without getting into sequence points and short-circuit evaluation, let's just say the results can be unpredictable to say the least (and could even vary based on compiler).  This is one of the reasons that many C++ programmers consider preprocessor macros to be evil.

To see this in action, try both definitions with `MIN(x++, y++)`.  For an even more evil possibility, consider the case of

```
result = MIN( x, ShouldOnlyBeCalledOnce_BecauseThisFunctionHasSideEffects(y));
```

While the preprocessor still certainly has its place (and there are things you can do with it that simply cannot be done any other way), with C++ in particular it is generally a good idea to determine if a non-preprocessor solution presents itself.
For example: With overloading, C++ implementations originally gave us things like

```
int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y); }
some_other_type min(some_other_type x, some_other_type y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }
```

Templates gave us a lot more, as in:

```
template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b) {
  return !(b < a) ? a : b;
}
```

The convenience of a macro, but without the side effects that can occur when a parameter is expanded more than once.  BTW, if you're wondering why the test is `!( b <  a) ? a : b;` versus `(a < b) ? a : b;`, it's because if `(a == b)`, `a` should be returned, and because less-than is the only relationship that needs to be defined for a given type to support a wide range of containers (among other things).