# How does this min() function work?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I came across this code:

```
int __min(int a, int b) {
    return ((a)-(((a)-(b))&((b)-(a))>>31));
}
```

I can imagine that it has something to do with the 2s complement, and that it only works for signed 32 bit integers, but after that I'm lost.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003601/how-does-this-min-macro-work), but I don't think that the functions are related, or am I wrong?

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why does this function work?
2. Is there a situation where `(a<b)?a:b` wouldn't work and this function would, or is this function just overcomplicated for fun?

**EDIT:** The function is written for GPU, so I think @Banex might be right about the purpose of writing it like this being to avoid branching.

Comment: I cannot guarantee the correctness, but I can imagine the main point of this function is to avoid branching.

Comment: @Banex The function was written for gpu, I think this would make sense, good point!

Comment: It also relies on signed int arithmetic overflow wrapping around

Comment: @M.M it practically does happen

Comment: @PaulStelian modern compilers can optimize out paths that contain integer overflow, so this code relies on the compiler not doing that, and instead defining behaviour of integer overflow or whatever

Comment: It also relies on shifting the sign bit of a negative `int`.

Comment: You can figure it out by separately looking for what is subtracted from `a` if `a` is less (then it must subtract `0`) and when `a` is greater (then it must subtract `a-b`) than `b`.

Comment: It is fundamentally range-limited in some sense, across all inputs a [quarter of them](http://haroldbot.nl/?q=%28a-%28%28a-b%29%26%28%28b-a%29%3E%3Es31%29%29%29+%3D%3D+min_s%28a%2C+b%29) cause wrong behaviour even when you use strict assumptions (eg 2's complement, wrapping, arithmetic shift). But that's not wrong, just a precondition.

Comment: @harold For what inputs would it fail, can you please clarify?

Comment: @PascalSommer for example a=1, b=0x80000000, assuming 32 bit. The link can generate some more examples.

Comment: @M.M it's actually possible that compiler changes the behavior to be indeed defined.

Comment: Dayum, that's a hacky code...

Comment: `a - (a - b & b - a >> 31);` more readable like that.

Comment: I'm also curious if the extra parenthesis (`(a)`) are there for any special reason.

Comment: But the most important question is: what advantage gives? ((a)<(b)?(a):(b)) is slower?

Comment: What I'm more curious is that is this really faster, in any condition or use case? Even in microprocessors? Is there really a gain from using this and not the simple if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is designed to work for 32 bit signed values. Let's break this down one step at a time.

```
((b)-(a))>>31)
```

The right shift operator essentially takes the highest bit in the 32 bit value, and sign-extends it to the remaining 31 bits. That's how the right shift operator works for signed values.

If `b` is greater than `a`, the result of the subtraction will be positive, the highest bit will be 0, and the result of this is 0.

If `b` is less than `a`, the result of the subtraction will be negative, the highest bit will be 1, and the result of this is -1. The highest bit gets shifted down to all the remaining bits. All bits in the 32 bit value will be set, which is -1.

You can verify this by yourself by writing a short program that places either a positive or a negative value into a 32 bit `int`, right-shifts it by 31 bits; then observing that the result will be either 0 or -1. As you know, in two-s complement arithmetic, the value `-1` has all of its bits set.

```
((a)-(b)) & (0 or -1, as the result of the previous operation).
```

So, if `b` is less than `a`, the right hand side value has all bits set, and the result of the bitwise `&` operator is the left hand side value. or `a-b`.

If `b` is greater then `a` the right hand side value has all bits 0, and the result of the `&` is 0.

In conclusion:

If `b` is less than `a`, the above expression evaluates to:

```
a-(a-b)

or

a-a+b

or

b
```

And if `b` is greater than `a`, the result of the expression is

```
a - 0

or

a
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
((a)-(b))&((b)-(a))>>31
```

i.e. without most superfluous parenthesis

```
(a - b) & (b - a) >> 31
```

evaluates to

```
a - b
```

if a > b, and to

```
0
```

otherwise, so if it is finally subtracted from a it is the same as

```
if (a > b)
   return (a - (a - b));
else
   return (a - 0);
```